# Parsing a text file in order to fill a HashMap

Tags: java, file, parsing, hashmap, text-files

```
/**
 * @(#)b.java
 *
 *
 * @author
 * @version 1.00 2012/5/4
 */
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.*;

public class b {


static void lireBddParcs(String nomFichier) throws IOException
{
    LinkedHashMap parcMap = new LinkedHashMap<Parc,Collection<Manege>> ();


    int n = 0;
    boolean existeFichier = true;

    FileReader fr = null;

    try
    {
        fr = new FileReader (nomFichier);
    }

    catch(java.io.FileNotFoundException erreur)
    {
        System.out.println("Probleme rencontree a l'ouverture du fichier" + nomFichier);
        existeFichier = false;
    }

    if (existeFichier)
    {
        BufferedReader entree = new BufferedReader(fr);
        boolean finFichier = false;

              while(!finFichier)
              {
               String[] line = entree.readLine().split("/t");;
               Parc p = new Parc(line[0], line[1], line[2]);


                  if (line == null)
                  {
                      finFichier = true ;
                  }

                  else
                  {
                      parcMap.put(p, null);
                  }

              }
                  entree.close();

    }


}


    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
      lireBddParcs("parcs.txt");

    }
}
```

Here's the content of the text file

```
Great America   Chicago Illinois
Magic mountain  Los Ageles  Californie
Six Flags over Georgia  Atlanta Georgie
Darien Lake Buffalo New York
La Ronde    Montreal    Quebec
The Great Escape    Lake Georges    New York
Six Flags New Orleans   New Orleans Louisiane
Elitch Gardens  Denver  Colorado
Six Flags over Texas    Arlington   Texas
Six Flags New England   Springfield Massachusetts
Six Flags America   Washington  D.C.
Great Adventure Jackson New Jersey
```

Here's the error I am getting:

```
error: unreported exception IOException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
```

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
 at b.lireBddParcs(b.java:54)
 at b.main(b.java:101)

Comment: So `split` did not return an array with at least 3 elements. Then you should try to understand why. Apparently, you use "/t" as separator. I guess you meant "\t".

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at b.lireBddParcs(b.java:53)
 at b.main(b.java:101)

Comment: You are going to get a npe at the end of the file as you use 'line' before checking to see if it is null

Comment: Any solution to this? I tried something, but it didn't work.

Comment: You should be doing something along the lines (no pun intended) of while ((line=entree.readline())!=null) to ensure you don't use line when it's null. You can then remove the  boolean finFichier making the code a bit simpler

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
 at b.lireBddParcs(b.java:54)
 at b.main(b.java:92)

Comment: if (existeFichier)
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(nomFichier);


              while (scan.hasNextLine())
              {

               String[] line = scan.nextLine().split("\t");
               Parc p = new Parc(line[0], line[1], line[2]);
               parcMap.put(p, null);


              }
                  scan.close();

    }

Answer (score 2):

Your method `lireBddParcs` is declared to throw an `IOException`, so your code doesn't compile, because your `main` method isn't handling it.  For your purposes, you may find it simplest to just add that `throws` to the `main` method as well:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException { ... }
```

Alternatievly, you can surround the call to `lireBddParcs` with a `try/catch` statement and log the exception somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

`java.io.IOException` is a *checked* exception, which means if you call any methods that declare throws `IOException`, you must either catch the exception or declare it in your method definition.

Hopefully this tutorial may help: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/